# React-Native code works without importing Platform module why?

Tags: react-native, react-native-native-module

I just added this code on my `home/index.js` file

```js
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    Expo.Notifications.createChannelAndroidAsync('chat-messages', {
        name: 'Chat messages',
        sound: true,
        vibrate: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        priority: 'max',
    });
    Expo.Notifications.createChannelAndroidAsync('reminders', {
        name: 'Reminders',
        sound: true,
        vibrate: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        priority: 'max',
    });
}
```

But after publishing to expo. I realize I did not import the `Platform` module.

Why does the notification channels was created and no error throw?

I have no global variables on the project btw.

Answer (score 0):

`createChannelAndroidAsync` is meant for android only so no need to check platform, react-native takes care of it

Comment: All right. But that does not solve my question. My question is why those methods get called if I didn't import the Platform module on the file?